# How To Make Thunderbird Compose Mail With "Body Text" As Default?

Tags: thunderbird, formatting

When I compose message it composes by paragraph as default.

[image]

How can I make it compose without paragraphs but regular body text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While creating a new message, click in menu *Format » Paragraph » {whatever you want}*.

This will become default style for new messages.

Comment: That didn't work with my current version of Thunderbird (45.0 installed on Ubuntu 15.10).  This worked: http://superuser.com/a/1042138/367972

Answer (score 10):

There is an option that controls the behavior in the preferences under "Composition" → "General"

> Use Paragraph format instead of Body Text by default

To compose in "Body Text" mode by default, you need to make sure that option is unchecked.

[image]

This dialog is [accessed differently on different platforms](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Menu_differences_in_Windows,_Linux,_and_Mac):

- Windows: "Tools" → "Options"
- Linux: "Edit" → "Preferences"
- Mac: "Thunderbird" → "Preferences..."

**Edited**: On older versions of Thunderbird the checkbox was labeled "When using paragraph format, the enter key creates a new paragraph"

Comment: One user reported that the HTML section of the preferences dialog doesn't appear when accessed through the preferences menu.  It does for me, but they could only get the option when going in through "Account Settings" - "Composition & Addressing" - "Global Composing Preferences..."

Comment: This particular option does not work for me in Thunderbird 102.9. It appears to have no effect whatsoever.

Comment: In Windows, v 115.5.1 (32-bit), this is under Hamburger > Settings > Composition > HTML style