# How to make Thunderbird compose mail with “Paragraph” as default?

Tags: thunderbird, formatting

I'm trying to do the exact opposite of [How To Make Thunderbird Compose Mail With "Body Text" As Default?](https://superuser.com/q/320135/90749). So my current default setting for composition is "Body Text", but  I want it to be "Paragraph".

[image: screenshot]

Just doing it the opposite way of the accepted answer doesn't work: If I select Format⇒Paragraph⇒Paragraph (from the menu bar), it does the formatting for the current e-mail; when I open another message, however, it starts out with "Paragraph" selected, but as soon as I type the first letter of my e-mail, it changes to "Body Text".

Is this a bug? Can anybody reproduce this behavior?

Comment: I [asked a similar question on mozillazine](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=2162183) in 2011. Still outstanding in 2014.

Answer (score 23):

I have found that to set the default to "Paragraph" or "Body Text", you need to navigate from the main menu:

Tools->Options->"Composition" region -> "General" tab

In the HTML section, find the option for "When using paragraph format, the enter key creates a new paragraph"

Select that option if you want "Paragraph" as the default.
Deselect that option if you want "Body Text" as the default.

I am using Beta version 45.0 of Thunderbird

Comment: Yep, looks like they added this in [Thunderbird 45.0](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=330891).

Comment: For linux users:
Preferences -> Composition -> General -> HTML -> "When using ..."

Comment: The checkbox is now labeled "Use Paragraph format instead of Body Text by default" instead of "When using paragraph format, the enter key creates a new paragraph"

Answer (score 4):

In Thunderbird 45+ you could change between "Paraghraph" and "Body Text" style
from

Tools -> Options (Preferences) -> Composition -> Check/Uncheck the following option:

"When using paragraph format, the enter key creates a new paragraph"

Answer (score 2):

In 91.9.1 I found it to be:

Tools -> Options (Preferences) -> Composition ->

Check box for:
Use Paragraph instead of Body Text by default.

[image: settings screenshot]